# How can I monitor my iPhone's charging status while plugged into my PC?

Tags: iphone

I'm working on a program that monitors your iPhone's charging statues while plugged into your PC. How can I do this in either VB, BAT or C++?

Comment: can you provide more details other than just a program that monitors charging status

Comment: I think you need to buy a Mac, a non-disclosure agreement, and a development license to do that. You also need to learn Cocoa/Objective C (http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html)

Comment: Should I post that as an answer?

Comment: The progrm will tell you in a textbox the current  staus of your iphones charge. Whats more to explain.

Comment: I think he's looking to monitor the charging status from his **PC**, not his phone.

Comment: That's what I meant. The software that Apple uses to connect to his IPod via his PC uses a proprietary driver. I don't think there's a public API to interface with that driver though, unless it's on a Mac.....

Comment: @IDWMaster: That may be true. I just wanted to clarify what was being asked. And he certainty wouldn't need to learn Objective-C for that.

Comment: I think if you want to do this without getting any APIs or accessing the proprietary driver, you would probably need to have the iTunes window open. Would that defeat the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the following on a timer (in ObjC):

```
-(NSString *)getBatteryPercent
{
    CFTypeRef blob = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo();
    CFArrayRef sources = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(blob);

    CFDictionaryRef pSource = NULL;
    const void *psValue;

    int i;
    int curCapacity = 0;
    int maxCapacity = 0;
    int percent = 0;

    int numOfSources = CFArrayGetCount(sources);
    //if (numOfSources == 0) return 1;

    for (i = 0 ; i < numOfSources ; i++)
    {
        pSource = IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription(blob, CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sources, i));

        psValue = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSNameKey));

        psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey));
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &curCapacity);

        psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSMaxCapacityKey));
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &maxCapacity);

        percent = (int)((double)curCapacity/(double)maxCapacity * 100);
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",percent];
}
```

To get the **state** of the battery:

```
-(NSString*)batteryStateStatus:(UIDeviceBatteryState)state
{
    switch ( state )
    {
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown:
            return @"Unknown";
            break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged:
            return @"Unplugged";
            break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging:
            return @"Charging";
            break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateFull:
            return @"Charged";
            break;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Requires the `IOKit.framework`

```
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/ps/IOPowerSources.h>
#include <IOKit/ps/IOPSKeys.h>
```

Comment: He's looking to monitor the charging status from his PC, not his phone.

Comment: I wonder: since it's possible to run this in the iPhone, it should be possible to expose this data to the computer, from your code, right? The computer could then poll your program on the iPhone and get the state.

Comment: got 1 error adding: #include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/ps/IOPowerSources.h>
#include <IOKit/ps/IOPSKeys.h>

Comment: Although IOKit is a public framework, not all of it is public ;-)

Comment: check out https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks for the class-dumped headers. There you will find IOKit. You may need to dump the rest of the framework to get the files you seek.